# Perl: Check if shell has redirected file handle

Tags: perl, shell, file-io, file-descriptor

I want to test if my perl program was called like:

```
my_program.pl 3>&1
my_program.pl 3>/tmp/file
my_program.pl 21>my.fifo
```

or:

```
my_program.pl
```

So I need a way in perl to test if a file descriptor by number is opened by the shell.

**Background**

This is intended as an possible extension of GNU Parallel. Currently GNU Parallel only make sure STDOUT and STDERR are not mixed, so this will mix up output:

```
parallel 'echo begin {} >&3; sleep 1; echo end >&3' ::: a b c 3>/tmp/file
```

whereas this will not because STDERR is buffered by GNU Parallel:

```
parallel 'echo begin {} >&2; sleep 1; echo end >&2' ::: a b c 2>/tmp/file
```

Now there is no need to spend resources on a file handle that is not opened. This will simply fail:

```
parallel 'echo begin {} >&3; sleep 1; echo end >&3' ::: a b c
```

So GNU Parallel should only buffer file descriptor 3 if that is actually being redirected outside GNU Parallel. But I do not know of a way to detect that in Perl.

On GNU/Linux I can go to /proc/$$/fd and see what descriptors are opened, but I would prefer a solution that does not depend on /proc/*/fd.

Comment: Why? Wouldn't a utility that behaves differently in each case violate the most basic Unix principles?

Comment: Unix principles aside, what is the reason for such complexity, and why would you have a need to externally choose the file descriptor?

Comment: None of your examples opens a file on the given descriptor. Your examples assume that `my_program` has opened them, and anything written to them will be redirected to the given file.

Comment: Actually, his example do open descriptor 3. Whether the program uses it or not is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is fairly easy: Just open the filehandle of the filedescriptor. If that fails, the filedescriptor is not opened:

```
perl -e 'for (1..1000) { my $fh; if(open($fh,">&=$_")) {$fh{$_}=$fh }  } print map{"$_\n"} keys %fh'  3>/tmp/foo
```

Minor issue is that fd 62 and up are used by bash for <(cmd).